# How to find sub-parts of .stl or .obj model programmatically?

Tags: stl, three.js, .obj, x3d, x3dom

I need to find sub-parts of .obj and .stl model and then I have to show them on browser.

I can show them on browser using three.js or X3DOM but I am unable to find sub-parts of these models.

Is there any algorithm or functionality to find sub-parts of .obj or .stl model? Kindly help.

Comment: Give you models a name when you load them so that you will be able to search for them.

Comment: In my case user is uploading 3d models. So I can not have static object names.

Comment: @gaitat : In my case user is uploading 3d models. So I can not have static object names.